# Inserting by name rather than position in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

In Postgres (version 9.4 fwiw), an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` query seems to insert based on column position rather than name:

```
pg=# CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE x (a int, b int);
CREATE TABLE
pg=# INSERT INTO x (a, b) SELECT 1 as b, 2 as a;
INSERT 0 1
pg=# SELECT * FROM x;
 a | b
---+---
 1 | 2
(1 row)
```

Is there any way to structure this query or something similar such that the columns would be inserted by name rather than positionally? I would want the result here to be:

```
pg=# SELECT * FROM x;
 a | b
---+---
 2 | 1
(1 row)
```

The context here is that the contents of the `SELECT` are being defined in a different place than the overall `INSERT` call, so it's difficult to enforce a common order.

Comment: There is no way to do this in SQL.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe check out the clever answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply move the query to a subquery:

```
INSERT INTO x (a, b) SELECT a, b FROM (SELECT 1 AS b, 2 AS a) src;
```

Comment: Ah, that's a great solution! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You define the order of the columns with the insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO x (b, a) 
SELECT 1 as b, -- maps to first column above
       2 as a; -- maps to second column above
```

Comment: Right, this much is clear, but I want this to work even if the order between the two parts of the query don't match... I'll clarify the question.

Comment: @nicolaskruchten I see what you're saying... Bottom line is, with an `insert ... select`, the values in the `select` will insert in the order defined in the parentheses of the `INSERT`